# Open app in one screen then animate to another

Tags: android, android-animation

I've been recently getting my feet wet with android development.

What I would like to do, is once the app is opened; a screen with a logo would appear, hold for a second, then animate left to another screen.

I have layouts designed. How would I go about animating those 2? The java part is where I don't quite know where to begin.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch the intent use `overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);` if this isn't the effect you are after you can change the animations to other ones in `android.R.anim` or define your own in XML and instead point to your anim folder `R.anim`

here is an example of a custom animation, you would save this in res/anim/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Comment: Looks like that worked! I ended up using a custom animation. Whats the best way to ease a custom XML animation? I want it to start slower and speed up towards the end. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

For those curious and are wanting to the same - having a splash page come up hang for a few seconds, then slide to an activity.

This is how I went with implementing the code. I found this from other users so I can't take credit for it, but thought it would be nice for people who might potentially stumble upon this.

```
public class logoSplash extends Activity {
private static final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME = 2000; // splash screen delay time

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.logo);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(logoSplash.this, fieldsActivity.class);

            logoSplash.this.startActivity(intent);
            logoSplash.this.finish();

            // transition from splash to main menu
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);

            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME);
    }
}
```